# Not sure if my induction proof is reasonable enough

Tags: graph-theory, induction, solution-verification

I am not going to write my full exact proof here, as the exact details are not really relevant. What I am unsure about is that is my proof "reasonable" enough, meaning that have I taken shortcuts that are not appropriate for a good proof.

So, as I am in the middle of showing that all automorphisms of a tree fix either a vertex or an edge. Essentially what I did was proof by induction on the number of vertices where we first handle cases $n = 1$ and $n = 2$. Then, I take any tree $T_1$ that has $n - 1$ vertices and construct a new tree $T_2$ by connecting a single new vertex $u$ to any vertex in $T_1$. As all elements of $T_1$ are the elements of $T_2$ it follows from the induction hypothesis that an automorphism fixes either a vertex or an edge of $T_2$.

Comment: I don't understand your argument.  As far as I can see, you simply assert the conclusion but provide no rationale for it.

Comment: I'd say the easiest way to prove the desired claim was to remark that the center of the tree must be invariant under any automorphism.  Then use the result that the center of a tree is either a single vertex or a pair of vertices connected by an edge.

Comment: Another way (well, the same idea in disguise) is the following: show that if $T$ is a tree and $\varphi$ is an automorphism of $T$, then $\varphi$ restricts to an automorphism of $T'$, the tree obtained from $T$ by deleting every leaf vertex. Then you can use induction.

Comment: Wouldn't this prove that all trees have the *same* fixed vertix or edge, namely the original vertex is always fixed. Is that true?

Comment: Okay, I think the issue is if $\phi: T_1 \to T_1$ and $T_1 \subset T_2$ you are assuming that the *only* automorphisms of $T_2$ can only be extensions of automorphisms of $T_1$ and alternatively that any automorphism of $\theta:T_2 \to T_2$ when we restrict it to $\theta_{T_1}: T_1 \to T_2$ via $\theta_{T_1}(t) = \theta(t)$ is an automorphism of $T_1$.  But that's not true.  It's not even a *map* to $T_1$.  It's possible $t\in T_1$ but $\theta (t) = $ the new vertex $\not \in T_1$.

Comment: In other words, while it may be true that every automorphism $\phi: T \to T$ has a fixed point, you claim that  every automorphism $\theta: (T\cup \{v\}) \to (T\cup\{v\})$ has a fixed point *because* $\theta_{\text{restricted to } T}: T\to T$ must be an automorphism and thus have a fixed point.  But that isn't true.  If $\theta(t) = v$ for some $t\in T$ then  $\theta_{\text{restricted to } T}: T\not \to T$ and $\theta_{\text{restricted to } T}: T\to (T\cup \{v\})$ is certainly *not* an automorphism *to $T$*.